# Making angular pdf download from api using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net-core, itext

Hy everybody.

I have created a pdf file on c# using iTextSharp but i don't know how to get it by angular and if my code is correct.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("comprovante-pdf/{doacaoId:guid}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GerarComprovantePdf(Guid doacaoId)
        {
            var pxPorMm = 72 / 25.2F;
            var pdf = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 15 * pxPorMm, 15 * pxPorMm, 15 * pxPorMm, 20 * pxPorMm);
            var path = $"comprovante_vaquinha_animal.{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy.HH.mm")}.pdf";
            var arquivo = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdf, arquivo);
            pdf.Open();

            // ADICIONANDO TÍTULO
            var fonteTitulo = new Font(fonteBase, 28, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.Black);
            var titulo = new Paragraph("Comprovante de Doação\n\n", fonteTitulo);
            titulo.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            titulo.SpacingAfter = 10;
            pdf.Add(titulo);

            var tabela = new PdfPTable(4);
            float[] largurasColunas = { 0.5f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 1.2f };
            tabela.SetWidths(largurasColunas);
            tabela.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 0;
            tabela.WidthPercentage = 100;

            pdf.Add(tabela);

            pdf.Close();
            arquivo.Close();

            var caminhoPdf = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/docs/" + path);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(caminhoPdf))
            {
                //Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo()
                //{
                //    Arguments = $"/c start {caminhoPdf}",
                //    FileName = "cmd.exe",
                //    CreateNoWindow = true
                //});

                Process.Start(caminhoPdf);
            }

            return CustomResponse();
        }
```

I tried to read articles but it is not working.